# Vertical fast scroll drawable in recycler view to move only between bottom navigation drawer and below toolbar like in google photos

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a main activity which has the navigation drawer and a `FrameLayout` to add fragments dynamically. The layout of one of the fragments has a `RecyclerView` and I want the `RecyclerView` to take the entire height of the device so that the `RecyclerView` scrolls beneath the `ToolBar` and bottom navigation. I am adding fast scroll to the `RecyclerView` but the verticalscrolldrawable is also scrolling between the entire height of the device but I want that to restrict between bottom nav and `ToolBar` like in google photos.

Sample Image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/55sh7.jpg

activity_main

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <import type="android.view.View" />

        <import type="com.nowfloats.laxmi.home.ui.HomeActivity" />

        <variable
            name="home"
            type="HomeActivity" />
    </data>

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".home.ui.HomeActivity">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/extended_fab"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.ExtendedFloatingActionButton.Icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/dp_16"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/laxmi_green"
            android:text="@string/add_new_inventory"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sp_12"
            android:visibility="@{home.fabObservable ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_add"
            app:iconPadding="@dimen/dp_4"
            app:iconSize="@dimen/dp_20"
            app:iconTint="@color/white"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_navigation"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="top|right"
            app:layout_insetEdge="bottom" />

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/navigation_drawer_height"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:alpha=".98"
            android:background="@color/laxmi_light_green"
            android:theme="@style/Widget.BottomNavigationView"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_drawable_colors"
            app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/BottomNavigationView.Active"
            app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/BottomNavigationView"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_drawable_colors"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

product_fragment-

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:clipChildren="false">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/navigation_drawer_height"
        app:fastScrollHorizontalThumbDrawable="@drawable/thumb_drawable"
        app:fastScrollHorizontalTrackDrawable="@drawable/line_drawable"
        app:fastScrollVerticalThumbDrawable="@drawable/thumb_drawable"
        app:fastScrollVerticalTrackDrawable="@drawable/line_drawable"
        tools:listitem="@layout/product_list_single_item" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/header_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        tools:context=".products.ui.ProductFragment">
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: You could grab [the source code for `FastScroller`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/recyclerview/recyclerview/src/main/java/androidx/recyclerview/widget/FastScroller.java) and modify it as needed. It's just an `ItemDecoration`/`OnItemTouchListener`, so there's no reason that you can't apply it externally. I did a quick test with it, and only had to grab that one class, so it's relatively simple.

Comment: Thanks mike. But I am unable to understand what to change in this file to make it working for me. How to add margin equal to bottom navigation view's height ? So that it just scrolls till bottom navigation view.

Comment: I'll clean up my test code from earlier, and try to put together a basic example later on, when I get a chance.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Will wait

Comment: OK, here's the modified class: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d95tLj3BXhCl1VZkAgRXql0MTFNd93ts/view?usp=sharing. And you would use it like such: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AMoQ_FPqJ2JT-ho8tH3Du7ia2oobCbUO/view?usp=sharing. If your `RecyclerView` is in a `Fragment`, and you do want the scroller bounded by the `BottomNavigationView` in the `Activity`, you'll have to somehow get the `BottomNavigationView` or it's height, at least, to the `Fragment`, to use in the `setInsets()` method.

Comment: You'll also need to remove all of the `app:fastscroll*` attributes from your `<RecyclerView>`, btw.

Comment: @Mike, Thanks for your answer. But the fastscroll drawable is not showing. Tried this -

InsetFastScroller fastScroller = new InsetFastScroller(recyclerView, R.drawable.thumb_drawable, R.drawable.thumb);
        fastScroller.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        recyclerView.post(() -> {
            fastScroller.setInsets(0, R.dimen.navigation_drawer_height);
        });

If I am adding the inset the fast scroller is not showing and if I don't add then it is showing and is working like it used to work before. The scroll bar moves under the bottom navigation bar.

Comment: `R.dimen.navigation_drawer_height` is not the actual measure. It's a resource ID that points to a dimension value. You would need to do `getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.navigation_drawer_height)` to get the real value.

Comment: Thanks Mike. It started showing now. Only one problem is happening now. If I drag the fast scroller by finger then it stops at the correct position (i.e just above the bottom navigation) but if I scroll my list now there are few more items in the list that were below the bottom navigation

Comment: Also when I scroll more to get the items, the fast scroll goes under the bottom navigation

Comment: Yeah, I just did a basic, proof-of-concept example, not anything production-ready; otherwise I would've posted an answer. I'll try to have another look at it later, if I get some time.

Comment: Sure Mike. Mean while I am also looking to fix this. But since I have no knowledge with custom views I am having problem understanding this